# Adapt thesis frontespizio

Tags: pdftex, thesis, frontespizio

I am learning LaTeX for my thesis work but I have really low understanding of LaTeX.
I need to make a frontespizio that exactly looks like this one made with word:

[image]

If can be useful I know that the *margins* of the file are top and bottom `2.54cm` and lef and right `3.17cm`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe you could start from the work available in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/lucach/frontespizio-unimib).

Comment: thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many approaches, but this could get you started...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel,graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\setstackgap{L}{1.5\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\sffamily
\noindent\scalerel{\includegraphics[height=1in,width=1in]{example-image}}{~~
  \Longstack[l]{University of Milan\\\bfseries School of Science\\
  \bfseries Department of Information\\\bfseries Bachelor of Information Science}}
\vspace{2in}

\centerline{\setstackgap{L}{\baselineskip}\bfseries\Huge 
  \Longstack{Multi-Line\\Title}}\vspace{1in}

\Large\noindent\Longstack[l]{
\textbf{Advisor:} \textit{primary advisor}\\
\textbf{Co-advisor:} \textit{secondary advisor}
}\vspace{1in}

\hfill\Longstack[r]{\textbf{Blah-blah bla}\\
your name\\
Matricola XXXXX}

\vfill\centerline{\textbf{Academic Year 2017--2018}}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!
Can I ask you if I should use pdflatex or lualatex?

Comment: @Giulio You're welcome.  The choice of engine is your call.  I prefer pdflatex for speed, but lualatex offers the ability to directly use system fonts.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, I think I have no more question for the moment, otherwise I hope to find you still available.
Best regards

Edit: is there a best way to structure a thesis?

Comment: @Simo I don't think the question "is there a best way to structure a thesis?" is relevant to this site.  This site's focus is on how to typeset things using the TeX family of compilers.  How to structure the document is a different discipline, unless by "structure", you mean how to organize one's source code in the most readable way.

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks.
But because I structured my latex document having a main.tex in which I insert the \include{} so I already have a \begin{document}, how can I modify you code to insert it in a frontispiece.tex file?